# How to copy a table from one mysql database to another mysql database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, linux, shell

I need to copy a table from one database to another. This will be a cronjob. Which one is the best way to do it? PHP script or Shell Script. The problem with PHP, both databases has different usernames and passwords so I can't do it like this.

```
CREATE TABLE db1.table1 SELECT * FROM db2.table1
```

Should I just connect first DB get all records and insert all to new database using WHILE loop or there is a better way?

I prefer a shell script to do this instead of PHP script.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you struggle with the PHP part, the SQL part, or the shell part?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd dump it. Much less complicated than anything PHP based.

```
mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 databasename > dump.sql
mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 databasename < dump.sql
```

MySQL reference: [4.5.4. mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//mysqldump.html)

Comment: Since I want to transfer only one table, I guess with a little bit mod this will work

mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 --add-drop-table databasename tablename  > dump.sql

thank you

Comment: If you use phpmyadmin, then it will be better.

Comment: You can even pipe it through: `mysqldump --user=root --password=remote_password the_database_name | mysql --user=root --password=local_password the_database_name`; usually this may be done from server to server using SSH-port-forwarding: `ssh -f -N -L 3307:localhost:3306 nmmn` (nmmn is one of my SSH-shortcuts, use a server-name+port instead); @Ergec for multiple tables use the param `--tables table1 table2`

Comment: Personally, I would cat the file back into mysql

Comment: also noteworthy to add that there is no space between `-p` and the password. Some tend to think it is a typo as well as if your password contains any special characters you will need to accent them with `\\`

Answer (score 60):

If you need to copy the table on the same server you can use `CREATE TABLE LIKE` and `INSERT`:

```
USE db2;

CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE db1.table1;

INSERT INTO table2  
    SELECT * FROM db1.table1;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much easier than mysqldump command-line.

Answer (score 36):

```
mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 databasename TblName | mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 anotherDatabase
```

It all can be done in a single command.

Answer (score 7):

```
$L1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user1', 'pass1');
$DB1 = mysql_select_db('database1', $L1);   

$L2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user2', 'pass2');
$DB2 = mysql_select_db('database2', $L2);   

$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1",$L1);
while($i=mysql_fetch_assoc($re))
{
    $u=array();
    foreach($i as $k=>$v) if($k!=$keyfield) $u[]="$k='$v'";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table2 (".implode(',',array_keys($i)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$i)."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(',',$u),$L2) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

user1, pass1, database1, table1 reffers to initial table
user2, pass2, database2, table2 reffers to copied table
$keyfield is the primary key of table

Answer (score 7):

One liner with different servers

```
mysqldump -h host1 -u user1 -ppassword1 databasename TblName | mysql -h host2 -u user2 -ppassword2 anotherDatabase
```

Comment: Optional you can also add an alternative port, e.q. `-P 3309`

Answer (score 5):

Phpmyadmin has inbuilt functionality to copy tables from one database to another. Otherwise you can go with Pekka or export table then import table.

Comment: IIRC, the inbuilt functionality will work only if the same user has access to both databases.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE TABLE db_target.cloned_table 
SELECT * 
FROM db_source.source_table;
```

Comment: Simple and straight. I wonder why no one found this useful as I'm the first one to upvote it.

Comment: This doesn't copy the keys over.

Comment: OP says each DB has different login+password, so can't use this.

Answer (score 3):

I'll put this answer up for anyone else looking for help.

If you don't have access to SSH then you can use PhpMyAdmin.

Simply:

1. browse to the table you want to move
2. Click the Operations tab
3. Use the MOVE or COPY to database function

If you come across privilege problems, you can temp grant a user Global permissions or add the same user to both databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec('mysqldump --user=username --password="password" --host=hostname --database=database table1 table2 > databasedump.sql');

exec('mysql --user=username --password="password" --host=hostname --database=database < databasedump.sql');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into dest.table select * from orginal.table;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<from database>`

```
create table <to database.new name> as (select * from <table to copy>);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think your answer got messed up. Please try to reformat it marking it as code.

Comment: As it stands this answer makes little sense. Please add some explanaation, and correct the snippet you've posted

Answer (score -2):

As it seems that nobody answered the initial question actually, here is my PHP script to backup a table from a remote MySQL server to a local MySQL server:

```
function backup_remote_table (
    $remote_db_host, $remote_login, $remote_password, $remote_db_name, $remote_table_name,
    $local_db_host, $local_login, $local_password, $local_db_name, $local_table_name
) {
    // Generating names with time stamps for local database and/or local table, if not available
    if ($local_table_name) {
        $applied_local_table_name = $local_table_name;
    } else {
        $applied_local_table_name = $remote_table_name;
    }
    if ($local_db_name) {
        $applied_local_db_name = $local_db_name;
        if (!$local_table_name) {
          $applied_local_table_name .= date_format(date_create(), '_Y_m_d_H_i_s');
        }
    } else {
        $applied_local_db_name = $remote_db_name . date_format(date_create(), '_Y_m_d_H_i_s');
    }

    // Local server connection
    $local_db_server = mysql_connect($local_db_host, $local_login, $local_password);
    $local_db_server = mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $applied_local_db_name, $local_db_server);
    mysql_select_db($applied_local_db_name, $local_db_server);

    // Remote server connection
    $remote_db_server = mysql_connect($remote_db_host, $remote_login, $remote_password);
    mysql_select_db($remote_db_name, $remote_db_server);

    // Getting remote table data
    $result_remote_table_info = mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE " . $remote_table_name, $remote_db_server);
    $remote_table_info = mysql_fetch_array($result_remote_table_info);
    $remote_table_description = substr($remote_table_info[1], 13);

    // Creating local table
    $sql_new_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $applied_local_db_name . "." . $remote_table_description;
    mysql_query($sql_new_table, $local_db_server);

    // Getting all records of remote table
    $result_remote_table_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name, $remote_db_server);
    while ($remote_table_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_remote_table_data, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        // Browsing records of remote table
        $sql_new_row = "INSERT INTO $applied_local_db_name.$applied_local_table_name (".implode(", ",array_keys($remote_table_row)).") VALUES (";
        $extra_sql = "";
        foreach (array_values($remote_table_row) as $value) {
            if ($extra_sql != "") {
                $extra_sql .= ",";
            }
            $extra_sql .= "'";
            $extra_sql .= mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $extra_sql .= "'";
        }
        $sql_new_row .= $extra_sql . ")";
        // Adding record to local table
        $result_new_table_row = mysql_query($sql_new_row, $local_db_server);
    }
    mysql_free_result($result_remote_table_data);

    return;
}
```

The solution above is not mine, I got it [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/php-script-to-copy-mysql-tables-from-one-server-to-another-by-database.58303/), with minor changes.

Comment: `mysql_connect` in 2019? Come on.

Comment: @miken32 what's the problem?

Comment: It's been deprecated for more than 10 years. It hasn't even existed since PHP 5, last version of that was released more than 5 years ago.

Comment: How about legacy support?

Comment: mysql_ functions have been removed in PHP 7, released Dec. 2015. There is no excuse for using them in 2020.

Comment: @ericek111, if a very old intranet web application needs only minor improvements -- should it be completely rewritten?

Comment: Do your applications still support Windows 95? Why would someone post a piece of code that has been defunct for half a decade? Even if for very old intranet web application, there should be a disclaimer.

Comment: @ericek111, what kind of disclaimer is needed here?

Comment: @ericek111, nobody forces you to read any solution for any problem, if the problem does not exist in your opinion. While these solutions might be useful for those developers whose customers ask for the support of old applications.