# PHP/MySQL: Copy Table and Data from one Database to another

Tags: php, mysql

Anoter question: What is the best way to copy a whole table from one Database without using something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DB2.USER SELECT * FROM DB1.USER;
```

This does not work because I can't use data from two Databases at the same time. So I decided to make this with php. There I had to cache all Data and then I'd create a table in the other DB.

But now - what would be the fastest way to cache the data? I guess there are closely everytime less than 1000 records per table.

Thanks for your input

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932608/how-to-copy-a-table-from-one-mysql-database-to-another-mysql-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export it to a .sql file and import to the new database.

In phpMyAdmin click the database you want to export, click <kbd>export</kbd>, check <kbd>save as file</kbd>, then <kbd>go</kbd>.

Then upload it to the new database that you want to duplicate the data in.

---

In a strict PHP sense, the only way I could think to do it would to be use of `SHOW TABLES` and `describe {$table}` to return the all the field names and structures of the records, parse that out, create your `create table` statements, then loop through each table and create `insert` statements.

I'm afraid the best I can do for you is a sort of ***prototype*** code that I would imagine would be *incredibly* server intensive, which is why I recommend you go an alternate route.

Something like:

```
<?php

    // connect to first DB

    $tables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tables)) {
        foreach($row as $value) {
            $aTables[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($aTables as $table) {
        $desc = mysql_query("describe " . $table);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($desc)) {
            $aFields[$i][] = array($row["Field"],$row["Type"],$row["Null"],$row["Key"],$row["Default"],$row["Extra"]);
        }
        $i++;
    }

    // connect to second DB

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aTables); $i++) {

        // Loop through tables, fields, and rows for create table/insert statements

        $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$aTables[$i]} (
                //loop through fields {

                    {$aFields[$i][$j][0]} {$aFields[$i][$j][1]} {$aFields[$i][$j][2]} {$aFields[$i][$j][3]} {$aFields[$i][$j][4]} {$aFields[$i][$j][5]},
                    {$aFields[$i][$j][0]} {$aFields[$i][$j][1]} {$aFields[$i][$j][2]} {$aFields[$i][$j][3]} {$aFields[$i][$j][4]} {$aFields[$i][$j][5]},
                    {$aFields[$i][$j][0]} {$aFields[$i][$j][1]} {$aFields[$i][$j][2]} {$aFields[$i][$j][3]} {$aFields[$i][$j][4]} {$aFields[$i][$j][5]},
                    {$aFields[$i][$j][0]} {$aFields[$i][$j][1]} {$aFields[$i][$j][2]} {$aFields[$i][$j][3]} {$aFields[$i][$j][4]} {$aFields[$i][$j][5]},
                    etc...
                }
            )';

            //loop through data

            $query .= 'INSERT INTO {$aTables[$i]} VALUES';
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $aTables[$i]);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $query .= '(';
                foreach ($aFields[$i][0] as $field) {

                    $query .= '"{$row[$field]}",';
                }
                $query .= '),';
            }
        mysql_query($query);
    }

?>
```

This is based off of [this script](http://pastebin.com/MS9R7TT4) which may come in handy for reference.

Hopefully that's something to get you started, but I would suggest you look for a non PHP alternative.

Comment: well, this should work as a job in php, and not requireing user input

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it, not original with me:

http://homepage.mac.com/kelleherk/iblog/C711669388/E2080464668/index.html

Comment: But I can't use commands like this, the only possibility is really doing it somehow with PHP...

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "dbname";
$sqlfile = "/path/backupsqlfile.sql";

$command='mysql -h' .$servername .' -u' .$username .' -p' .$password .' ' .$dbname .' < ' .$sqlfile;
exec($command);
```