# Insert a mysqli_result Object

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a mysqli_result:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Is it possible to directly do an INSERT with this result? (Data needs to be transferred in another database) like `$another_db->insert($result)` or at least to convert the whole result Object to a simple Mysql Insert String without iterating over the result.

Comment: why not do it in a single sql query rather than query/php/query?

Comment: If your user has access to both databases - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595178/copy-fields-from-one-database-to-another-in-mysql

Comment: The 2nd database is on a different server

Comment: so, as they reside on different servers presumably the credentials are different?

Comment: Yes, due to security reasons the 2nd database runs on a different host with different credentials

Answer (score 1):

I do a workaround like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$newsql="";
while($row =  $result->fetch_object())
{
    $newsql = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES (";
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        $newsql .=  "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$value)."',";
    }
    $newsql = substr($newsql,0,-1);
    $newsql .="); ";
}
// $newsql can be inserted.
```