# MySQL copy table to different database with same credentials

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the standard MySQL functions that PHP has built in for copying one table to an new table.
This works perfect when the tables are in the same database. But I want to copy it to another databasename with same user and password.

Any suggestions how to achive this?
(Since `$database` can only contain 1 databasename)

Error shown is `Table 'torzahttp_rsw.torzahttp_rsw.kwaliteit' doesn't exist`
`torzahttp_rsw`is the database name, and `kwaliteit` the table name.
Why is the databasename used twice?

```
// Create a new MySQL database connection
if (!$con = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database)) {
    die('An error occurred while connecting to the MySQL server!<br><br>' . $con->connect_error);
}

// Create an array of MySQL queries to run
$sql = array(
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `backup_db.backup_table`;',
    'CREATE TABLE `backup_db.backup_table` SELECT * FROM `live_db.live_table`'
);

// Run the MySQL queries
if (sizeof($sql) > 0) {
    foreach ($sql as $query) {
        if (!$con->query($query)) {
            die('A MySQL error has occurred!<br><br>' . $con->error);
        }
    }
}

$con->close();
```

Comment: Do you get any messages/errors?

Comment: Although you connect to a database, you can still access other databases using the method you currently do ( `databasename.tablename` ) as long as the user you connect as has the rights to that database and the database is on the same server (AFAIK)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy table to another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932608/how-to-copy-a-table-from-one-mysql-database-to-another-mysql-database)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov no it does not. I need an php script to copy certain tables.

Comment: @NigelRen now I was able to see an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this solution to create an mysql dump first and then processioning it.

```
//DB 
$user = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxx';
$host = 'localhost';
$database_old = 'old_db';
$database_new = 'new_db';

$table = 'kwaliteit';
$file = 'kwaliteit.sql';

exec('mysqldump --user='.$user.' --password='.$password.' --host='.$host.' '.$database_old.' '.$table.' > uploads/'.$file);

exec('mysql --user='.$user.' --password='.$password.' --host='.$host.' '.$database_new.' < uploads/'.$file);

unlink('uploads/'.$file);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html):

> If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example, write `` `my-table`.`my-column` ``, not `` `my-table.my-column` ``.

Your code:

```
$sql = array(
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `backup_db.backup_table`;',
    'CREATE TABLE `backup_db.backup_table` SELECT * FROM `live_db.live_table`'
);
```

should look like this:

```
$sql = array(
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `backup_db`.`backup_table`;',
    'CREATE TABLE `backup_db`.`backup_table` SELECT * FROM `live_db`.`live_table`'
);
```

Or, just drop the backticks altogether.